# Is there anyway I can attract more attention to an answer to an old question?

Tags: discussion

In this case, I wrote an answer to an old question and I wanted to know (without sounding spammy) if there is anyway to attract attention to the answer just to see if it meets the criteria for "good answer" so I can work on future answers.

Comment: Probably it is worth mentioning that a new answer [bumps](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bumping) the question to the first page (when question are sorted by recent activity) - which makes at least some people notice the new answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the post had attracted only 50 views over the past decade, your answer will likely not change the situation (beside the initial "bump" to the first page).

When you answer an old question, I suggest you to look for duplicates (usually, there are a lot) and find the best duplicates, which we call post A. The post is good if, say, it has the most views, has already several nice answers, and the question is well-written. Then post your answer there, if your answer is a new one. Then look for other duplicates in MSE, and [flag](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) it as a duplicate of post A. That will direct a lot more views to post A. In the mean time, you can also improve post A (say, give it a more descriptive title, fixing the formatting, adding a bit of contexts and so on).